# adding <input> element to <trigger> causes serivce launch to crash?

Tags: google-mirror-api

I'll admit, I'm pretty rusty with android development.  It's been a few years for me.  As a refresher, I wanted to change the countdown app so that i could set the starting time with just my voice.

Simple, right?

I loaded up the sample apps and threw the timer app onto my glass.  Everything worked. I was thrilled.

Then, following the instructions here [GDK voice input](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/voice) i was able to change the "ok glass" command.  Still worked.  Cool.

Then, i added the  string to trigger the voice transcribing function after 'launching' the timer app.  Now, i can "ok glass" to launch the timer app, and i can say a few numbers and see them transcribed, but as soon as i stop the "swipe down to cancel" shows up and then shortly thereafter the app crashes and i end up back at my home screen.

Is there something simple that I have over looked?  I added a `Log.i()` call to the `onStartCommand()` and it shows up in logcat ... when i remove the `<prompt>` element from the `remind_me.xml` file

Here's the excerpt from the manifest:

```
<service
            android:name="com.google.android.glass.sample.timer.TimerService"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_timer"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                android:resource="@xml/remind_me" />

</service>
```

**WORKING:**

```
<trigger keyword="@string/voice_start_timer">
</trigger>
```

**NOT WORKING:**

```
<trigger keyword="@string/voice_start_timer">
    <input prompt="@string/voice_timer_prompt" />
</trigger>
```

So what am i missing? What additional info do you need?
Thanks for your time and patience. I appreciate it!

Comment: Same here. Will mention tomorrow on the second day of the Google Glass Workshop in SF.

Comment: Can you post some errors from the logs? I was able to get the <input> working properly, building an app from scratch

Comment: There isn't anything plain obvious in the logs: https://gist.github.com/nicolasgramlich/7559416

Comment: Occasionally the logs also contain:

11-20 00:01:48.231: E/StrictMode(772): class com.google.glass.voice.VoiceAnnotationActivity; instances=2; limit=1
11-20 00:01:48.231: E/StrictMode(772): android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.google.glass.voice.VoiceAnnotationActivity; instances=2; limit=1
11-20 00:01:48.231: E/StrictMode(772):  at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)

Comment: That gist looks a whole lot like my log output (sorry, i forgot to attach it!).

But yes, that exception does seem to happen to me around the time my service is started.

I am glad that somebody can bring it up to a Glass dev at their conference tomorrow; i didn't get an invite :(

Comment: Just reported it. It might be because we are trying to start a Service. Supposedly it works when starting an Activity. They are checking it out right now.

Comment: Thanks!  If you need to get more info from me, PM me.  Should I bother with an official bug report or will your proxy be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some free time over the Holiday 2013 break.

Testing this with the new XE12 OS and updated GDK works.  problem solved by updating to newest software.